# using a simple component (dumb) to create a list of buttons and use parent method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create a simple dashboard. I'm just exploring some new ideas I have in react and it's been so long I'm running into a strange problem I can't seem to understand.

I have a very simple class:

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  HandleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.name === "createEvent") {
      console.log('event clicked');
    }
    console.log(e.name);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="row">
        <ButtonList onClick={this.HandleClick}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and then I have a simple function outside of the class that creates a button list:

```
function ButtonList(props) {
  return (
    <button name="createEvent" onClick={props.HandleClick}>Create Event</button>
  )
}
```

the idea behind this was instead of having so much stuff inside one superclass I wanted to separate simple functionality, like a button or *command* list if you will, that opon clicking would eventually change the state of the navbar.

I'm not sure how I would return that values of the button, or aside from that pass a parameter into the button from a child prop.

For example instead of doing `HandleClick = (e) =>` and actually look for a parameter, how would I pass that in the child function where it gets used (if there were many more buttons)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should be doing instead:

On your parent component, you can use arrow functions to pass the parameters within `handleClick`. This will allow you to listen to the events on your child `ButtonList` component with the parameters passed onto the method.

In addition, if you want to access to `name` attribute of your button, you should be calling `event.target.name`, as `name` is part of the `target` property of the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) interface.

```
export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "createEvent") {
      console.log('event clicked');
    }
    console.log(e.target.name);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="row">
        <ButtonList onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And on your `ButtonList` functional component, you should pass the onClick event to the `onClick` props which was defined as part of the `ButtonList` component.

```
function ButtonList(props) {

  const onClick = (e) => {
    props.onClick(e);
  };

  return (
    <button name="createEvent" onClick={(e) => onClick(e)}>Create Event</button>
  )
}
```

I have created a demo over [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-glade-ijmyq).